# solr 7.7 crash with 100% heap usage

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj, solrcloud

I am migrating from solr 6.6 to solr 7.7. with same config as solr 6.6 running same set of queries and data, solr 7.7 is crashing with GC issues. I tried to take heap snapshot and it does look like this

```
     num     #instances         #bytes  class name (module)
-------------------------------------------------------
   1:      96550804     2456456648  [B (java.base@11.0.5)
   2:      96197629     2308743096  org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRef
   3:      96139148     2307339552  org.apache.lucene.index.Term
   4:       1839819      440114232  [I (java.base@11.0.5)
   5:       1800360      417537648  [Lorg.apache.lucene.index.Term;
   6:       1799767       57592544  org.apache.lucene.search.PhraseQuery
   7:       1803933       43294392  org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanClause
   8:       1376256       33030144  org.apache.solr.update.VersionBucket
   9:        137210       32160648  [C (java.base@11.0.5)
  10:         36817       16598560  [J (java.base@11.0.5)
  11:         43901       11346568  [Ljava.lang.Object; (java.base@11.0.5)
  12:        290325        6967800  java.lang.String (java.base@11.0.5)
```

from the GC analysis the old GC is reaching peak and triggers full GC which takes so long time and trigger STW event pausing all solr operations.

what could be the cause of this ?

Answer (score 0):

Double-check the queries you send to solr if they contain `rows` count to something very high value.  Try to restrict the `rows` count to max 10,000 in the request for quicker GC that's what I personally found safer. Use pagination for pulling a huge number of docs if required. It doesn't matter if your query result is only a few hundred, it will increase GC time if you use a very large value in the `rows` parameter in the request.

If this is not the case you should tune your GC settings.